# jQuery file tree browser and Django

Tags: jquery, ajax, django, file, tree

anybody knows a tutorial on using jquery file tree browser on Django. I followed this tutorial:
http://www.abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/ but I cant make it work, I'm confused with this code block:

```
    $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#explorer').fileTree({
            root: '/windows/',
             script: 'jqueryFileTree.py',
            expandSpeed: 1000,
            collapseSpeed: 1000,
            multiFolder: True
            }, function(file) {
            alert(file);
    }); 
});
```

question: in line ==> script: 'jqueryFileTree.py',
jqueryFileTree.py on what directory will I put this file?

or maybe can I put the contents of jqueryFileTree.py in my views.py?